# finite dimensional irreducible unitary representations

Tags: representation-theory, abelian-groups

Let $(\pi,V)$ be a unitary finite dimensional unitary representation of a commutative Lie group $G$. I want to show that $\dim(V)=1$ if and only if $\pi$ is irreducible.

I think the following arguement works to show the $"\implies"$ direction.
Assume that $\dim(V)=1$. Then the only subspaces of $V$ are trivially $0$ and $V$ hence $\pi$ must be irreducible.

But I am not sure how to do the other direction. If we assume that $\pi$ is irreducible, then the only invariant subspaces of $V$ under $\pi$ are $0$ and $V$. I also know that schurs lemma gives $\text{End}(V)$ consists of $\lambda\cdot I $ with $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ but I'm not sure how this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $g\in G$. Then the map$$\begin{array}{ccc}V&\longrightarrow&V\\v&\mapsto&\pi(g)(v)\end{array}$$is an endomorphism of $G$-modules (this is where the fact that $G$ is Abelian is used). So, by Schur's lemma, there is some $\lambda_g\in\mathbb C$ such that$$(\forall v\in V):\pi(g)(v)=\lambda_gv.$$Since $G$ acts by multiplication by scalars, *every* vector subspace of $V$ is a submodule. So, since this representation is irreducible, $\dim V=1$.

Comment: Why is $v \mapsto \pi(g)v$ not an endomorphism if $G$ is not Abelian? I would have thought this is always an endomorphism

Comment: Try to prove that it is and you will see why.

Comment: I realize what I was doing wrong. $v \mapsto \pi(g)v$ is always in $End(V)$. But is it is not always in $End_G(V)$. But I am not sure what the condition to be in $End_G(V)$ is

Comment: If $\varphi\in\operatorname{End}(V)$, then $\varphi\in\operatorname{End}_G(V)$ if$$(\forall g\in G)(\forall v\in V):\varphi\bigl(\pi(g)v)=\pi(g)\varphi(v).$$

Comment: Where are we using that $\pi$ is unitary?

Comment: @some_math_guy I had no need for that hypothesis.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, At the very end, the only subspaces are 0, and V, how do we rule out that the submodule is not {0} ?

Comment: @some_math_guy The space $V$ itself is not $\{0\}$. So, since every vector subspace of $V$ is a submodule and since $V$ is irreducible, $V$ has to be $1$-dimensional.