# Why is $ V \longrightarrow V: v \mapsto \pi(g)(v)$ an endomorphism of $G$-modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, modules, lie-groups, group-actions

I found this question here  [finite dimensional irreducible unitary representations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3418284/finite-dimensional-irreducible-unitary-representations)
But I having trouble with the answer given there

Let $(\pi,V)$ be a unitary finite dimensional unitary representation of a commutative Lie group $G$ and let   $\pi$ be irreducible.

Take $g\in G$. Consider the map$ V \longrightarrow V: v \mapsto \pi(g)(v)$

**Why is it an endomorphism of $G$-modules  ?**  I know it has something to do with the commutativity
I would say that the map is an endomorphism of $\Bbb R$-modules, because V is a real vector space, so an $\Bbb R$-module. Wy should it be and endomorphism of G-modules? I can't say that V is a vector space over G, right? Since G is not a field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets write down explicitly:

$$f:V\to V$$
$$f(v)=\pi(g)(v)$$

Or simply $f=\pi(g)$. It is linear because $\pi(g)$ is. It is a bijection because $\pi(g^{-1})$ is inverse of $\pi(g)$.

So the only question is whether it is a $G$-module morphism. So let $h\in G$. Then

$$f(\pi(h)(v))=\pi(g)\big(\pi(h)(v)\big)=\pi(gh)(v)$$

Now since $G$ is abelian then $gh=hg$ and therefore

$$f(\pi(h)(v))=\pi(gh)(v)=\pi(hg)(v)=\pi(h)\big(\pi(g)(v)\big)=\pi(h)\big(f(v)\big)$$

and thus $f$ is a $G$-module morphism.

Note that it wasn't relevant that $V$ is finite dimensional, unitary or that $G$ was a Lie group. This works for any Abelian group $G$ and any representation $V$ over any field or even ring. This even works outside of linear world, i.e. for $G$-sets, except $f$ is obviously no longer linear in such case.

Finally note that $G$ being abelian is an important assumption. Otherwise $f$ need not be a $G$-module morphism. There are counterexamples. It is not hard to construct one, at least if you consider finite non-abelian $G$. You just need to consider $G$ acting on itself (in the natural way), and extend that to a vector space with $G$ as its basis.

**// EDIT**

> I can't say that V is a vector space over G, right? Since G is not a field.

The term "$G$-module" does not mean "module over $G$" as in "module over a ring". Those two terms share the same "module" word, but in fact mean something different. The term "$G$-module" means literally the same thing as representation of $G$ (in a more general sense, i.e. not necessarily Lie, potentially over any ring, not only reals).

Note that these two concepts, i.e. $G$-modules and modules over ring, actually are related. There's a natural equivalence between $G$-modules (representations) over a ring $R$ and modules over [the group ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_ring) $RG$. Here of course you consider $R=\mathbb{R}$ the ring/field of reals. The problem is that there's no natural/useful topology on $RG$, even if both $R$ and $G$ are topological. Which makes this approach worse. Still useful in purely algebraic context though. But that's a story for another time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To talk about a G-module morphism, first the sets must be G-modules. Shouldn't I check that first?

Comment: I puzzles me that V is an R-module, but also a G-module apparently? That means any (right/left )action G over a vector space V is a (right/left) G module?

Comment: @some_math_guy $G$-module is just another word for representation of $G$ (sometimes with some additional "natural" conditions, based on the type of group considered)

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft G is an abelian group, so V is a Z-module, so what makes G a ring in order to talk about a G-module?

Comment: @some_math_guy it is not a ring. The term "$G$-module" has its own meaning (as Tobias said: the same as representation of $G$). It is not directly related to "modules over ring" (although there does exist connection through group ring $RG$, but lets not make it more confusing). Different things, even though use the same "module" word. Which I understand why it is confusing.

Comment: @some_math_guy Please read my comment again. Your reply seems to completely ignore what it says.

Comment: Is a homomorphism of G-modules the same as an intertwiner of representations?

Comment: @some_math_guy yes, that's the same thing.